# Custom Email Filter in Solr doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, solr, schema

I have created a Solr filter to retrieve email from a specific text and return only the email!

This is my code:

```
public final class NormalizeAffliationFilter extends TokenFilter {
 private CharTermAttribute charTermAttr;
   protected NormalizeAffliationFilter(TokenStream ts) {
     super(ts);
     this.charTermAttr = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
   }
   @Override
   public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
     if (!input.incrementToken()) {
       return false;
     }

   String token =charTermAttr.toString();
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9_.-]+)@([a-z0-9_.-]+[a-z])");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(token);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(matcher.find()){
            sb.append(matcher.group());
        }
        sb.append("  ");
     String email = sb.toString();
       charTermAttr.setEmpty();
       charTermAttr.copyBuffer(email.toCharArray(), 0, email.length());

     return true;
   }
```

I've added the field type and field in schema.xml

```
 <fieldType name="emailnormalized" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="ir.pandapp.NormalizeAffliationFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="ir.pandapp.NormalizeAffliationFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="ir.pandapp.NormalizeAffliationFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="mods.affiliation" type="emailnormalized" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
```

I've added some sysout in my code to get the logs and it works! It gets the token and only the email token would return!

I've also tested it on analysis in Solr:

[image: my results]

After all of this when I search in Solr, it doesn't work!

like if the field value is:"aaaaemail:something@something.com" and I search:"aaaa" it returns this doc!

But it should only return this when I search:"something@something.com". I have checked schema browser it has only indexed the emails(the correct form).
I've got no idea  what to check next! Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Hi, could you clarify this "After all of this when I index my data, it shows the whole text". What shows the whole text? Is it the results of a query?

Comment: @CliffWillsher yes I edited it! thanks for noticing!

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't implement this with `solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory`?

Comment: @MatsLindh as I understood that filter replaces the text if it has specific pattern! but I want to remove any token without that specific pattern! and I don't think my filter is the problem here

Comment: What is your query ?
And how is your request handler defined ?

Comment: Are you doing an explicit field search as in "field:value" or is there a default field lurking in there that's matching the query?

Comment: @AlessandroBenedetti My query is mods.affiliation:"aaaa" and this it the request handler:   <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>

Comment: @CliffWillsher I am using explicit field search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No custom code required. You need to invert what is described in [Remove email address from solr indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655719/remove-email-address-from-solr-indexing)

As such you will make use of the [UAX29URLEmailTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-UAX29URLEmailTokenizer) to add type meta data to the tokens of your text and then use the [TypeTokenFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-TypeTokenFilter) to only let those types pass that are of your liking. In your case this is only `<EMAIL>`.

Alter your field type `emailnormalized` in your **schema.xml** as follows

```xml
<fieldType name="emailnormalized" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TypeTokenFilterFactory" 
                types="email_type.txt" useWhitelist="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Create a file named **email_type.txt** in your conf folder, should be the same place where your schema.xml is resident. That file needs just one line of content

```
<EMAIL>
```

Should you have trouble with the delimiters that are used by that Tokenizer, you can tweak that using the [PatternReplaceCharFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory). The CharFilters may go before a Tokenizer. This would also work with the sample text you have in your image, replacing the colons for a blank.

```xml
<fieldType name="emailnormalized" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" 
                    pattern=":" replacement=" "/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TypeTokenFilterFactory" types="email_type.txt" useWhitelist="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```